# Confusing straight lines problem

Tags: geometry

Can someone please provide me a start with this question, I will solve the rest on my own. Thanks.

In $\triangle{ABC}$, coordinates of point $A$ are (1,2). If $y=x$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $x-2y+1=0$ is the angle bisector of $\angle{BCA}$. Equation of BC is $ax+by-5=0$, find value of $a+b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first let us compute the intersection point of $y=x$ and $x-2y+1=0$ this point has the same distance from $A(1;2)$ to $B(x_B,y_B)$ since it is situated on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$
this point $S$ has the coordinates $S(1;1)$ and $$SA=1$$ and it must be $$SB=\sqrt{(1-x_B)^2+(1-y_B)^2}=1$$
the distance of the point $S(1;1)$ to $BC$ must be the same as the distance from $$S(1;2)$$ to $AC$ since $S$ is situated on the angle bisector of $\angle BCA$

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks :) Will accept after I solve it.

Comment: hello Stacy i have added the next step

Comment: What to do next now?

Comment: Got it, thanks. accepted :)

Comment: You may complete the answer if you want to for future references.

Comment: ok i'm working Stacy